# What is an efficient way of selecting multiple colors via Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

Background: The following snippet is what I (intend to) use in a `Manipulate` form where up to 12 different colors can be selected:

```
 Manipulate[{sliderCol1},
  Row[{"Kleur 1: ", ColorSlider[
     Dynamic[sliderCol1] ,
     AppearanceElements -> {"SwatchSpectrum"},
     ImageSize -> {200, 40},
     BaselinePosition -> Scaled[.25]]}
   ]
 ]
```

To make this work with fields `sliderCol1` to `sliderColn` (where $n$ = 2, …, 12), I see no other option than copying the code in `Row` so many times.

**Question: Is there a less verbose way of implenting a multiple (here 12) color selector using color sliders?**

Comment: Note you can create a swatch as simply as `Manipulate[x, {x, Red}]`, or maybe `Manipulate[x, {{x, Red, "Kleur 1"}, Red}]`.

Comment: That gets me going a while. Thanks - ( I got the snippet from a Wolfram Demonstrations file!, anyway I 'll bang my head against the wall a few times. )

Comment: I realize it does not answer your question---which is why I kept it as a comment.   In general, it would be interesting to know how to implement custom controls which can be used in the standard way, i.e. `control[Dynamic[var]]` would set `var`.  `var` in this case could be a list of colours.  I feel rusty though so maybe this is just not the right approach ...

Comment: I feel a similar question was asked already, but can't find it. Maybe it's on SO. Maybe someone remembers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With this one you just click the circle to be color-edited. No need to pick an index number first.

```
DynamicModule[{x = 1},
 Manipulate[c[[x]] = color;
  Grid[
   Table[
    Setter[Dynamic[x, (color = c[[#1]]; x = #1) &], i*4 + j, 
     Graphics[{FaceForm[c[[i*4 + j]]], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 40]
     ], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 4}
    ]
   ], {color, Red},
  Initialization :> {c = ConstantArray[Black, 12]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I used `Dynamic`'s alternative syntax form, where you determine what should happen if the argument needs to be updated. In this case I use it to set the starting color of the color selector to be the current color of the circle being clicked. Otherwise the color of the circle would be set by the current setting of the color setter. This may be or may not be how you want the control to behave. Just change it to `Dynamic[x]` if you want to have the other behavior.

Comment: That's the one I will use, thank you.

Comment: Neat idea :) +1

Comment: To avoid having global variables in `Manipulate` you could add `x` and `c` to the list of controls with `ControlType -> None`.

Comment: @Heike that, or use a DynamicModule. Will update tonight.

Answer (score 11):

If to have multiple controls is not essential, to avoid interface overcrowding, one could try another approach. You do not need 12 controls to control 12 different things. You could just have 2 inter-connected controls: the *color* and the *indexer* telling the *color* which thing to change. Here is an example:

```
Manipulate[c[k] = color;
 GraphicsGrid@Partition[Graphics /@Table[{c[a], Disk[], 
 Text[Style[ToString[a], Blue, 30]]}, {a, 12}], 4],
 Button["Random Reset", Table[c[a] = Hue[RandomReal[1, 3]], {a, 12}]],
 Button["Black Reset", Table[c[a] = Black , {a, 12}]],
 {color, Red}, {{k, 1, "index"}, Range[12], Setter}, 
 Initialization :> {Table[c[a] = Hue[RandomReal[1, 3]], {a, 12}]}]
```

[image]

Notice `c[k]` are global variables here - localize if leaks can cause problems.

Comment: Very neat indeed, if the index numbers were placed in a grid to match the physical layout of the colour disks, that would be even sweeter.

Comment: @image_doctor thank you, done.

Answer (score 7):

This is one way to do this

```
With[{n = 12},
 With[{names = ToExpression[Array["sl" <> ToString[#] &, n]]},
  Manipulate[
   GraphicsGrid[Partition[Graphics[{{#, Disk[]}}] & /@ names, 4], 
    Spacings -> {0, 0}],

   Evaluate[Sequence @@
     MapIndexed[
      {{#, Hue[#2[[1]]/n], Row[{"Kleur ", #2[[1]]}]}, 
        ColorSlider[#, AppearanceElements -> {"SwatchSpectrum"},
          ImageSize -> {200, 40}, 
          BaselinePosition -> Scaled[.25]] &} &, names]
    ]]]]
```

Here, `names` contains a list of variables `{sl1,...,sl12}`. This list is used to construct a sequence of controls. Since `Manipulate` has attribute `HoldAll`, we need `Evaluate` to construct the controls before they're used in `Manipulate`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]