# How to create a multi-selectable setterbar with colored buttons

Tags: programming, dynamic, gui-construction

Background: consider the following code-snippet.

```
  Dynamic@Grid[
    Table[Setter[Dynamic[idx, (idx = #1) &],
      i*6 + j, 
    Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20]], 
    {i, 0, 1}, {j, 6}]]
```

This code creates two rows of clickable disk images. So if idx=10 is run, the 10th disk looks pressed. I want to make this control multi-selectable. So if idx={1,12} run, the first and last disks look pressed. ( In my application the disks may have different colors, edge properties and opacity. ) - See also: [What is an efficient way of selecting multiple colors via Manipulate?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4055/what-is-an-efficient-way-of-selecting-multiple-colors-via-manipulate)

**Question: How to create "a multi-selectable setterbar with colored buttons" ?** ( preferably based on the snippet above, but not necessarily ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this provide the functionality you are looking for? Note that a multi-selectable [`SetterBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetterBar.html) is a [`TogglerBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TogglerBar.html). The only problem with the latter is that it cannot be partitioned into a multi-row grid. For your particular problem, I would rather use `Button` instead of `Setter`:

```
list = {};
Dynamic@list

Grid[Table[
   DynamicModule[{pressed = False}, With[{idx = i*6 + j},
     Button[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20], 
      pressed = ! pressed; 
      list = If[pressed, Append[list, idx], DeleteCases[list, idx]], 
      Appearance -> Dynamic@If[pressed, "Pressed", Automatic]]]],
   {i, 0, 1}, {j, 6}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A somewhat different approach is to concatenate multiple `TogglerBar`s: this has some drawbacks, as the output is always sorted (if not then output order depends on the order of clicks **and** the order of `TogglerBar` rows).

```
TogglerGrid::usage = 
  "TogglerGrid[x, {val.1, val.2, ...}, n] represents a \
TogglerBar-like control (with setting x and with toggler buttons for \
values val.i to include in the list x), but with togglers arranged in \
a grid, with a maximal n elements per row.";

TogglerGrid[var_, ref_] := TogglerGrid[var, ref, Length@ref];
TogglerGrid[Dynamic[var_], list_List, n_] := Module[
   {set, ref = Evaluate@list, temp},
   temp = {} & /@ ref;
   set = TogglerBar[
       Dynamic[temp[[#]], 
        Function[{$x}, temp[[#]] = $x; 
         var = Sort@(Join @@ temp)]], {ref[[#]]}] & /@ 
     Range@Length@ref;
   Grid[
    Partition[set, n, n, {1, 1}, {}],
    Alignment -> {Center, Center},
    Spacings -> {0, 0}]
   ];
TogglerGrid[var_, arg___] := 
  Module[{dummy = var}, TogglerGrid[Dynamic@dummy, arg]];
```

Test the function:

```
x = {};
Dynamic@x
TogglerGrid[Dynamic[x], 
 Table[Graphics[{Hue@RandomReal[], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20], {10}],
  5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I think so, will try it now.

Comment: In your example I would like to have {5,7,9} as a result.

Comment: @ndroock1: Please see edit. It is more along the lines of your posted code.

Comment: That does it, although your previous answer had some nice features regarding building the grid.

Comment: @ndroock1: I re-added `TogglerGrid`. I only removed it previously because I realized it is not exactly an answer to your question. Hope it can be of any use.

Comment: Yes it is! Thank you very much for the re-post

Comment: It's worth your while to link to answers such as this as I hadn't seen it before. +1

Comment: Does the $ sign serve any special purpose in Function[{$x},...] ?

Comment: @kmutiny No, it does not, any symbol works and would be local to the `Function`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting at least in M9, [`TogglerBar`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TogglerBar) supports an [`Appearance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Appearance) option that produces a grid:

```
DynamicModule[{idx = {}},
    {
    TogglerBar[
        Dynamic[idx],
        Table[i -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize->20], {i, 12}],
        Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {2, Automatic}
    ],
    Dynamic[idx]
    }
]
```

[image]

where I show an image after clicking a few times.

Answer (score 0):

In the following, I tried to start with the complete list, with sorting, and deleting duplicates. It works except that you have to click twice the first time on each number. Can this be fixed? It would also be nice if the button changed color to red when off. I tried, but couldn't get it to work. And if each circle had its number
in it.

```
n = 12;
list = Range[n];
Dynamic@list

gOn = Show[Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}], ImageSize -> 20];
gOff = Show[Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}], ImageSize -> 20];
this = {gOn, gOff};

tb01 = 
 Table[Show[gOn   , 
   Graphics[{Text[Style[ToString[k], White, Bold]]}]], {k, 1, 12}]
    tb02 = 
 Table[Show[gOff, 
  Graphics[{Text[Style[ToString[k], White, Bold]]}]], {k, 1, 12}]

flags = ConstantArray[1, n];

Grid[Table[DynamicModule[{pressed = False, hold = i*6 + j, that},
   With[{idx = hold},
    If[flags[[hold]] == 1, that = tb01[[hold]], 
 that = tb02[[hold]]];
    Button[that, pressed = ! pressed;
     list = 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Sort[If[pressed, Append[list, idx], DeleteCases[list, idx]]]],
     Appearance -> 
  Dynamic@If[pressed, "Pressed", Automatic]]]], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 6}]]
```