# Wrapping EventHandler by Table

Tags: dynamic, output-formatting, output

I am making a grid on the screen. The grid is composed of different expressions. I want all of them to have a `Gray` background, which turns into a `White` background upon a mouse click, each expression separately. Instead of the whole thing I only show it here for a row of 3 elements to simplify the example. This works:

```
DynamicModule[{col1 = Gray, col2 = Gray, col3 = Gray},
 Row[{
   EventHandler[Dynamic@Style[x, Background -> col1],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (col1 = 
        col1 /. {Gray -> White, White -> Gray})}](*End eventhandler*),
   EventHandler[Dynamic@Style[x, Background -> col2],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (col2 = 
        col2 /. {Gray -> White, White -> Gray})}](*End eventhandler*),
   EventHandler[Dynamic@Style[x, Background -> col3],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (col3 = 
        col3 /. {Gray -> White, White -> Gray})}](*End eventhandler*)
 }]
]
```

However, as soon as I try to automate the same code, i.e., instead of writing each element of the row separately, to use the `Table` statement it does not work. 
This is my trial of the automation that does not work:

```
DynamicModule[{col1 = Gray, col2 = Gray, col3 = Gray},
 Row[Table[
   EventHandler[
    Dynamic@Style[x, Background -> ToExpression["col" <> ToString[i]]],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (Background -> ToExpression["col" <> ToString[i]] =
        Background -> ToExpression["col" <> ToString[i]] /. {Gray -> Green, 
          Green -> Gray})}](*End eventhandler*),
   {i, 1, 3}]]
]
```

I would like to understand what is wrong. Is it possible to wrap `EventHandler` by a `Table` statement?

Comment: Somewhat related post [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7563/89).

Comment: It's difficult to say what the bigger problem is that Alexei is trying to solve.  But it does smell like a problem that might be more suitably handled by `Toggler` and friends than `EventHandler`, as István might be suggesting by his linked content.  That having been said, I think Mr.Wizard points to a better method for tracking a variable number of values.

Comment: Let me explain. There is an approach in pedagogics and psychology to train the attention of children with slight problems of concentration. The exercise is that the teacher uses a hand lamp to light up one out of lots of task preliminarily drawn on the blackboard. The child is trained to only focus on the highlighted task. This method has drawbacks, especially if applied in a small room without a large blackboard ans so on.

Comment: Now my idea is to make the same on the computer screen. I imagine it in the following way. There should lots of exercises all with a gray background.The teacher/parent switches one of them into say, green by the mouse click. Alternatively it may automatically go randomly. The task are all different and are also formed using random numbers generator. Since it is assumed for a primary school chile, they are simple, like addition, multiplication, division, squares and alike. Now as soon as one exercise is highlighted, the result should be due to be entered into an input field and checked.

Comment: Upon checking a signal should be given to inform the child, if he is right, or not. There may be also other things to do, say, to count the amount of right and wrong answers, and so on.  Previously I already did simple training interactive toys. They were, however, more simply in that they only exposed one task at a time. Here I want, however, to expose many tasks at once, but only make one of them due to solve. That is what stays behind my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several issues here.  You need to "inject" the symbol name into the expression using `With` (or similar) to prevent trying to make an assignment to `ToExpression["col" <> ToString[i]]`.  Further, you've got spurious `Background ->` expressions which do not belong.  (I also use `Symbol` in place of `ToExpression`.)  That gives us:

```
DynamicModule[{col1 = Gray, col2 = Gray, col3 = Gray},
 Table[
   With[{bg = Symbol["col" <> ToString[i]]},
    EventHandler[Dynamic@Style["x", 50, Background -> bg],
     {"MouseClicked" :> (bg = bg /. {Gray -> Green, Green -> Gray})}]
   ],
   {i, 1, 3}
 ] // Row
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a problem with this however, because the symbols you create inside `Table`, whether you use ToExpression or Symbol, are not localized as you expect.  If you set `col1 = "Fail!"` outside of the module you will see this problem.

Probably a better method is to use [indexed objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MakingDefinitionsForIndexedObjects.html) as follows:

```
DynamicModule[{col},
 col[_] = Gray;
 Table[
   With[{i = ii},
    EventHandler[Dynamic@Style["x", 50, Background -> col[i]],
     {"MouseClicked" :> (col[i] = col[i] /. {Gray -> Green, Green -> Gray})}]
   ],
   {ii, 1, 7}
 ] // Row
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A bit more concisely with [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html), [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html), and [`TimesBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimesBy.html):

```
DynamicModule[{col},
  col[_] = 1;
  EventHandler[
    Style["x", 50, Background -> Dynamic @ {Gray, Green}[[col@#]] ]
    , {"MouseClicked" :> (col[#] *= -1)}
  ] & ~Array~ 7 // Row
]
```

Changing the position of `Dynamic` also changes the behavior of the output when the kernel is terminated; the line resets but the X's can still be clicked to toggle.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like what I had in mind. I should admit, however, that I do not understand why the scoping of the parameter "i" here makes the job. I see though that without it does not work as intended. Could you comment this?

Comment: @Alexei are you referring to the `With[{i = ii}` thing?

Comment: Yes. I mean this thing.

Comment: @Alexei please see this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121

Comment: @Alexei may I know why you un-Accepted this answer?  I argue that indexed objects are still the best way to go.  Among other things `Unique[]` [gets quite slow](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11459/121) when there are many Symbols in the system.

Comment: This is a misunderstanding. I accepted the both answers. I am mostly grateful for the both. I very clearly checked the acceptance button, but I see now it unchecked. This is probably some computer problem. I am doing this once more now.

Comment: It is strange, as soon as I accept one, the acceptance of another disappears. What should I do?

Comment: @Alexei You're doing nothing wrong. =)  The system is set up such that you can only Accept *one* answer, though you can change your Accept or remove it entirely at any time.  You are free to Accept whatever answer you please.  (Usually an un-Accept means you either found a problem with the answer or a better one came along afterward, which is why I asked.)

Comment: OK, I understand. However, in this case the both answers seem to offer a solution. To decide between them I am going to try to solve my problem within the both approaches and see which one is simpler. I still did not make my mind about it. That is why I wanted to accept the both.

Answer (score 4):

When handling symbols like you do, I find it best to avoid converting from and to strings. This is typically needed in other languages to do meta-programming, however due to Mathematicas philosophy being that everything is an expression, meta-programming can be accomplished simply by holding evaluation order. Here is a simple implementation of your functionality:

```
 SetAttributes[ClickAbleField, HoldAll]
 ClickAbleField[var_] := 
    EventHandler[
        Dynamic@Style[x, Background ->var]
    ,{"MouseClicked" :> (var = var /. {Gray -> Green, Green -> Gray})}
    ]

 DynamicModule[{col1 = Gray, col2 = Gray, col3 = Gray}, 
   Row[{Hold[col1], Hold[col2], Hold[col3]}] /. Hold -> ClickAbleField
 ]
```

Note that I use hold to prevent imidiate evaluation of the `col` variables, but also tell `ClickAbleField` to hold it's input arguments using the attribute `HoldAll`, such that the mentions inside it's definition will reference the unevaluted variable, and not it's current value.

If you have long lists of variables, you can also just pass them around in `Hold` and map functions over them like you would ususally do, then release the hold afterwards:

```
 DynamicModule[{col1 = Gray, col2 = Gray, col3 = Gray},
  Row[List @@ (ClickAbleField /@ Hold[col1, col2, col3])]
 ]
```

If you want to generate something based on arbitrary lists of variables, you could use `Unique` to generate the variables:

```
vars = Table[Unique["col"], {5}];
Hold[DynamicModule[initvars, body]] /. {
  initvars -> Replace[Hold @@ vars, a_ :> (a = Gray), 1],
  body -> Row[ClickAbleField /@ vars]
} /. Hold -> List // First
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems not quite what I am after, or I do not understand something.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I added an example of generating your interface with arbitrary number of variables. the initial code simply showed how to accomplish the code you already posted.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [FlipView](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FlipView.html)

```
 Row[Table[FlipView[Style["x", 50, Background -> #] & /@ {Gray, Green, Red}], {5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Short code! +1  (Though in fairness perhaps not as flexible as my method.)

Comment: Mr.Wizard, thanks for the vote.