# In a DynamicModule, is it possible to use multiple EventHandler declarations?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, eventhandler

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrapping EventHandler by Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13440/wrapping-eventhandler-by-table)

I am running *Mathematica* 7.  However, I am new to using `Dynamic`, `DynamicModule`, `EventHandler`, and the like.

I would like to create a `Graphics` object containing `numDisks` `Disk` objects, where `numDisks` is a positive integer.  I would like each of the `Disk` objects to be `Red`, `Green`, or `Blue`.  The default color is `Red`, but if a disk is clicked, that disk goes to the next color, cyclically (`Red`-->`Green`-->`Blue`-->`Red`-->...).  Is it possible to accomplish this using a `DynamicModule` and multiple `EventHandler` declarations?

I have tried the following.  This code generates `numDisks` disks in a row.  When the user clicks anywhere within the `Graphics` box, the color of *all* three disks changes to the next color in the sequence.

```
radius = 1;
numDisks = 3;

DynamicModule[{col = Red},
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[
   Table[{Dynamic[col], Disk[{2.5*(i - 1), 0}, radius]}, {i, 1, 
     numDisks}],
   PlotRange -> All],
  {"MouseClicked" :> (col = 
      col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Blue, Blue -> Red})}]
 ]
```

[image: Three Disks]

However, what if I would like each of the `numDisks` `Disk` objects to have its own color, which can be changed *independently* of that of all of the other `Disk` objects?  Is this possible?  Can this be accomplished somehow using multiple `EventHandler` declarations?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13440/121

Comment: To the person who voted to **reopen**: please tell me why.  I would be happy to reopen this if you can explain to me why it is not a duplicate.  By my reading and by comparing the Accepted answers to both questions I think it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to create an independent `DynamicModule` for each `EventHandler`.  Otherwise, the single variable `col` will control the color for all of the disks, as you're witnessing.  Your code can be rearranged as follows:

```
radius = 1;
numDisks = 3;

Graphics[Table[
  DynamicModule[{col = Red}, 
   EventHandler[{Dynamic[col], 
     Disk[{2.5*(i - 1), 0}, 
      radius]}, {"MouseClicked" :> (col = 
        col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Blue, Blue -> Red})}]], {i, 1, 
   numDisks}], PlotRange -> All]
```

EDIT:

Okay...per your request in the comments, here's a variation which uses a single `DynamicModule`, but makes the `col` variable a list which is then referenced separately by the individual `EventHandler` constructs.  The only thing that's tricky about this is that you have to inject the value of `i` from the `Table` inside of `EventHandler` and `Dynamic` using `With`.

```
radius = 1;
numDisks = 3;

DynamicModule[{col = Table[Red, {numDisks}]}, Column[{
   Graphics[
    Table[With[{i = i}, 
      EventHandler[{Dynamic[col[[i]]], 
        Disk[{2.5*(i - 1), 0}, 
         radius]}, {"MouseClicked" :> (col[[i]] = 
           col[[i]] /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Blue, 
             Blue -> Red})}]], {i, 1, numDisks}], PlotRange -> All],
   Dynamic[col]}]]
```

I wrapped this with a `Column` just to illustrate what the value of `col` is and the principle that you could access `col` from code outside of the graphic.

Comment: Thank you!  This might be a separate question, but is it possible to somehow save the current color state of each `Disk` to a list?  For example, suppose that I have three disks: (1), (2), and (3).  Further suppose that I click the disks so that disk (1) becomes `Red`, (2) becomes `Green`, and (3) becomes `Blue`.  Is it possible to save -- perhaps dynamically -- the current color states of (1), (2), and (3) to a list?